# Dict lookup in a JSONField

Tags: python

I want to check if a key value pair is present in the JSONField
For instance, I want to check if {'a': 'b'} is present in {'data': [{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}]}

How can I implement functional programming to achieve this?

I tried the straightfoward approach, i.e. checked for the key, value individually.

Comment: What does this have to do with django? Do you want to filter such instances?

Comment: Do you want to check whether the whole dict/list structure contains any dict with that key-value pair? Have you tried to implement that check recursively?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, It is a Django JSONField. I tried using ORM for explicity querying but that's not what I want. It simply does not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```py
def check_json_key_value(obj, key, value):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for x in obj:
            if check_json_key_value(x, key, value):
                return True
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        if key in obj and obj[key] == value:
            return True
        for x in obj.values():
            if check_json_key_value(x, key, value):
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply do this:**

```
def key_val_pair_check(data, pair_dict):
    for d in data:
        return all(item in d.items() for item in pair_dict.items())

json_data = {'data': [{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}]}
data = json_data.get('data')

pair_dict = {'a': 'b'}
is_pair_exist = key_val_pair_check(data=data, pair_dict=pair_dict)
print(is_pair_exist)

pair_dict = {'e': 'f'}
is_pair_exist = key_val_pair_check(data=data, pair_dict=pair_dict)
print(is_pair_exist)
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
```